# Differentiation: $y = 9x + \frac{3}{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiate $y = 9x + \frac{3}{x}$

I think the first step is to turn $\frac{3}{x}$ into a more "friendly" format, so $x$ to the power of *something* maybe? How do I get $x$ with an index from $\frac{3}{x}$?

Comment: 9+(-3/x^2) ,,,,

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{3}{x} = 3x^{-1}$
Then the derivative is $3*(-1)* x^{-2} = - \frac{3}{x^2} $.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks

Comment: Remember the definition of negative and rational powers of x, it will make it much more simple to calculate derivatives e. g. x^(1/2) is the square root, and 1/x^a is x^(-a)

Comment: Yes I understand

Answer (score 2):

Since you referenced implicit differentiation ...

$xy = 9x^2+3\\
x dy + y dx = 18x dx\\
x dy = dx(18x - y)\\
dy/dx = (18x-y)/x = 18-y/x
= 18-(9+3/x^2)
= 9-3/x^2
$.

A simpler example...

$y = 1/x\\
xy = 1\\
x dy + y dx = 0\\
dy/dx = -y/x
= -1/x^2
$.

And in case you confuse f abd g ...

$y = f/g\\
gy = f\\
g dy + y dg = df\\
\\
dy = (df - y dg)/g
= (df-f dg/g)/g
=(g df - f dg)/g^2
$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply the definition (whenever $x\neq 0$):
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 9x + \frac{3}{x} \Rightarrow f'(x) & = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(9(x + h) - 9x + \frac{3}{x + h} - \frac{3}{x}\right)\\\\
& = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(9h - \frac{3h}{x(x + h)}\right)\\\\
& = \lim_{h\to 0}\left(9 - \frac{3}{x(x+h)}\right)\\\\
& = 9 - \frac{3}{x^{2}}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps !